# Anyone can help me apply this on my database?

Tags: prolog

```
query(USER, PWD, DB, QUERY, Columns, Rows) :-
    atom_concat('-p', PWD, PPWD),
    process_create(path(mysql), ['-u', USER, PPWD, '-D', DB, '-e', QUERY], [stdout(pipe(Out)),stderr(std)]),
    read_record(Out, Columns),
    read_records(Out, Rows).

read_record(Out, Fields) :-
    read_line_to_codes(Out, Codes),
    Codes \= end_of_file,
    atom_codes(Line, Codes),
    atomic_list_concat(Fields, '\t', Line).

read_records(Out, [Record|Rs]) :-
    read_record(Out, Record),
    !, read_records(Out, Rs).
read_records(Out, []) :-
    close(Out).

assertz(Clause).
```

Comment: This is obviously written for a MySQL database. Is your database MySQL? It seems clear that `USER` is your db user name, `PWD` is the password for the user, `DB` is the database name, `QUERY` is the query you want to execute. What else do you need to know in order to try it? The statement `assertz(Clause).` by itself, out of any other context here isn't meaningful.

Comment: where to put the name of tables and the name of columns?

Comment: It's all built into the query string. `QUERY` here is a MySQL query. That's how the code you're showing is structured.

Comment: @jschimpf: What is specific here to the tag [tag:prolog-toplevel]?

Comment: I provided an answer to your question. Did it help?

Answer (score 1):

Your not really making much sense. By applying to a database, I assume you have a series of grounded facts, and you wish that this set of predicates can run with it.

If that's the case, you need to read up on unification in prolog.

Answer (score 1):

As I described in my comment, it seems clear that `USER` is your database user name, `PWD` is the password for the user, `DB` is the database name, `QUERY` is the query you want to execute. The `QUERY` is the full MySQL query string you want to execute. All information regarding the query (including what table, what fields, and the conditions) are included in that query string. It's a standard, MySQL query string. It's understood that the user name and password you provide have proper permissions to execute the query you will give in `QUERY`.

For example, suppose you have a MySQL database called `mydb`.
Suppose also that `mydb` has a table called `mytable` which looks like this:

```
id    foo    bar
--    ---    ---
 1    ick    poo
 2    oh     yeah
```

And suppose further that your MySQL database `mydb` is accessibly by user `fred` with password, `freds=password`. Then you can make the following query with that Prolog code you're showing:

```
?- query('fred', 'freds=password', 'mydb', 'select * from mytable', Cols, Rows).
```

Which will yield:

```
Cols = ['id', 'foo', 'bar']
Rows = [['1', 'ick', 'poo'], ['2', 'oh', 'yeah']]
```

Or you can do:

```
?- query('fred', 'freds=password', 'mydb', 'select id, bar from mytable limit 1', Cols, Rows).
```

Which will yield:

```
Cols = ['id', 'bar']
Rows = [['1', 'poo']]
```